# In C++, why can int initialize a variable using new operator but double cannot?

Tags: c++, new-operator

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int* i = new int(75);
    double* d = new double(3.14159);     
    printf("%d\n",*i);
    printf("%d\n",*d);
}
```

In the above code i returns a value of 75 however, d returns 1.
I tried explicitly initializing it as

```
*d = 3.14159
```

But the value is still returned as 1.
Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Use `%f` to print double.

Comment: Or use `std::cout` instead of `printf`.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` for gcc and clang).

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot about the delimiter. Thanks @Ville-Valtteri

Comment: @ANIRUDHMS To be precise: it is not a 'delimiter', it is a 'format specifier'...

Answer (score 2):

Use this for printing.

```
cout<<*i;
cout<<*d
```

"%f" is the (or at least one) correct format for a double if you want to use printf for printing the value of the double in C++.